# avoid sock puppet detection(creating two account) in a site

Tags: browser, proxy, ip, mac-address, fingerprint

some sites block your account if they detect a sock puppeting (creating more than one account for one person).
Somehow when you create an account**(A)**  ,then **reinstall your system** and create an account(B) , the site doesn't detect a sock puppet! 
**I want to know  what the system reinstallation did to cheat the site?**

1. it can't be the Mac address : it's physical and doesn't change after reistallation ! am i right?
2. could be creating a file somewhere in the system and the reinstallation deleted it ? if so.. how to find it?

Answer (score 1):

Nobody can say for certain what changed, as this is dependent upon the specific site and how their anti-sock-puppet mechanisms work.

It's reasonable to suggest that the site in question may rely on either a cookie or local storage for authentication or session management, and values in these cookies might be used as part of sock-puppet detection (ie. correlating behaviors of separate accounts).

An OS re-install would destroy all existing cookies and local storage.